# Method to check "dutch" postal code in java

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I'm trying to create a method in java to validate a dutch postal code.
the dutch postal code consist 6 characters which contain 4 numbers (first 4 chars) and 2 letters (last 2 chars) so for example 1010AB.

I made a boolean to return false if the postcode is not within standard and true if it is. 
I'm getting stuck with checking the last 2 letters.

I've created a loop for the first 4 numbers, but I don't know how to go further from here to check the letters aswell.

My java method:

```
public static boolean checkPostcode(String postCode) {


        boolean value = false;
        if (postCode.length() == lengthPost) {
            for (int i = 0; i < postCode.length(); i++) {
                if (i <= 4) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(postCode.charAt(i)) {
                        value = true;

                 else{
                            if (Character.isLetter(postCode.charAt(i))) {
                                value = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
     return value;
    }
```

You van ignore the last else, because that is the point where I get stuck....

If someone can help me that would be great!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like it would be easier to solve with regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution using regex:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("1234AB"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("5678MN"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("0123AB"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("1023AB"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("1230AB"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("AB1234"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("123456"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("ABCDEF"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("12345A"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("A12345"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("A12345B"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("1ABCDE6"));
        System.out.println(checkPostcode("1ABCD6"));
    }

    public static boolean checkPostcode(String postCode) {
        return postCode.matches("[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{2}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
true
true
false
true
true
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

**Non-regex solution:**

```
public static boolean checkPostcode(String postCode) {
    if (postCode.length() != lengthPost || postCode.charAt(0) == '0') {
        return false;
    }
    if (postCode.length() == lengthPost) {
        for (int i = 0; i < postCode.length(); i++) {
            if (i < 4 && Character.isLetter(postCode.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
            if (i > 3 && Character.isDigit(postCode.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: the first number of the postal code needs to be between 1 and 9 because it can not be 0. If I use regex, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the first 4 symbols are digits, so the if condition should be

```
(i < 4)
```

because otherwise you check the first 5 symbols for a digit

Answer (score 1):

While you could solve this problem with regular expressions, it is also possible to solve it along the lines you have chosen. I would write two helper methods, one to check that all characters within a given subsequence of a `String` are digits and another to check for letters. Like,

```
private static boolean allDigits(String s, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean allLetters(String s, int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then the `checkPostcode` can *delegate* to those two methods. Like,

```
public static boolean checkPostcode(String postCode) {
    if (postCode != null && postCode.length() == 6) {
        return allDigits(postCode, 0, 4) && allLetters(postCode, 4, 6);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And if you choose to use a *regular expression* compile it with a [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for better performance. Like,

```
private static Pattern POSTCODEPATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\d{4}[A-Za-z]{2}");

public static boolean checkPostcode(String postCode) {
    return postCode != null && POSTCODEPATTERN.matcher(postCode).matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sa, ss, sd are not valid (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_the_Netherlands )
to check for those too:

```
Pattern dutchZips = Pattern.compile("^[1-9][0-9]{3} ?(?!sa|sd|ss)[a-z]{2}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

return dutchZips.matcher(zip).matches();
```